# How can I change the Comparer of ASP.NET's Request.Form collection?

Tags: asp.net, .net, collections, icomparer

ASP.NET's `Request.Form["key"]` collection uses a case-insensitive Comparer.  This is screwing me up because I've got form POST data that looks like:

```
"subject=MySubjectLowerCase&Subject=MySubjectUpperCase"
```

As a result, `Request.Form["subject"]` (or `Request.Form["Subject"]` for that matter) return both values:

```
MySubjectLowerCase,Subject=MySubjectUpperCase
```

but what I want is the single value for my particular key, with case-sensitivity.

How can I change the Comparer to case-sensitive?

Comment: Using case sensitive parameter values is a bad idea. Use some other method to differentiate them.

Comment: tvanfosson - I don't control the post; it comes from an external application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the built-in comparer.  However, if you are willing to parse the raw entity body, you can access it via HttpRequest.InputStream, GetBufferlessInputStream, or GetBufferedInputStream.  The first two will make Request.Form inaccessible; the latter preserves Request.Form in case another piece of the request pipeline depends on it.  This should be done only as a last resort as writing a parser can be a very tricky exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The Request.Form is a NameValueCollection object. You will need to implement a customized IComparerInterface for it. You will find this useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.100).aspx

Having said that, tvanfosson is right that it's a bad idea to implement case sensitive parameter values.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't control the post; it comes from an external application.